# Clear way to check if n consecutive values out of N are bigger than a threshold and save their index (corresponding to n)

Tags: python

I would like to locate *n* consecutive points out of *N* from a vector of data with length *L*.
Example: 2 out 3 consecutive points bigger than a certain threshold *tr*.

```
data = [201,202,203, ..., L]
L = len(data)
N=3
tr = 200
for i in range(L-N+1):
    subset = data[i:i+N]
    if (subset[0] > tr and subset[1] > tr) or (subset[1] > tr and subset[2] > tr):
       "save index"
```

I would like to know how to save the index of the elements that satisfy such conditions?
Is there an elegant way to do it more flexibly (n out of N)?

Comment: In this case the expected output would be, [0,1,2], the position/index in data. I can change data to be diferent.

Comment: Other example, data = [190,204,240], the output would be [1,2].

Comment: If your code above is working but you have questions about the approach, efficiency, style etc., consider asking on Stack Exchange's [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site instead of (or in addition to) here.

Comment: @CurtF. in addition wouldn't it be considered duplicated? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that Alin T. answer is not completely correct. For example: `getOver([203,100,205])` we will `get [0,2]`, which is not quite correct as there're not n (2) consecutive elements greater than a defined threshold (200). The output should be an empty array ([]).

Here is a solution:

```
def xoutXconsecutive(data, tr, n):
    out = []
    for i in range(0, len(data)-n+1):
        subset = np.array(data[i:i+n])
        isNotConsecutive = [False]*n
        for j in range(0, len(subset)):
            if (subset[j] < tr):
                isNotConsecutive[j] = True
        aux = False
        for k in range(1, len(isNotConsecutive)):
            if isNotConsecutive[k]:
                aux = True
                break
        if ( (isNotConsecutive[0] == False) and (aux == False) ):
            out += [i+(n-2), i+(n-1)]
        elif ( (isNotConsecutive[0] == True) and (aux == False)):
            out += [i+(n-1)]

    return np.unique(out)
```

`print(xoutXconsecutive([203,100,205], 200, 3))`

[]

Answer (score 0):

Start by flagging the items that are within the desired range.  Then perform a rolling sum of the flags and select the matching indexes in subranges that have the minimum count of flagged items.

```
from itertools import islice

def getOver(data,minVal=200,minCount=2,window=3):
    inRange = [minVal<=n for n in data]
    groups  = (islice(inRange,s,None) for s in range(window))
    indexes = { i for s,r in enumerate(zip(*groups)) if sum(r)>=minCount
                for i in range(s,s+window) if inRange[i]}
    return sorted(indexes)

print(getOver([100,205,205]))
[1, 2]

print(getOver([201,205,205,150,190,203,100,205]))
[0, 1, 2, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Thank you! Not quite want I pretend, e.g., when data window is the last 3 position [100,205,205], the expected return should be [1,2],  index 1 and 2, corresponding to 205 and 205, respectively, are both > 200 and consecutive.

Comment: I see.   Adjusted my answer to return individual indexes instead of ranges.  Note that I now use a set because overlapping ranges could include the same indexes.